# Laravel broadcast does not send events to pusher

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, pusher, laravel-echo

I've set up Laravel to use pusher to send events for Laravel Echo, but the events I fire from artisan console don't reach pusher.
The events i fire from the pusher debug console are working fine, so the frontend part is okay.
Could the vagrant VM interfere with it?

My .env file

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
...
PUSHER_KEY=<key>
PUSHER_SECRET=<secret>
PUSHER_APP_ID=<app_id>
```

My broadcasting.php

```
'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),
...
'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver'  => 'pusher',
        'key'     => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
        'secret'  => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
        'app_id'  => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster'   => 'eu',
            'encrypted' => true
        ],
    ],
    ...
]
```

The event:

```
class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
         return [new Channel('chat.'.$this->conversation->id)];
    }
}
```

The event is fired from an Observer class, which observes a models `created` event.

```
public function created(Chat\Message $message)
{
    event(new NewMessage($message));
}
```

The Observer is registered in the `AppServiceProvider`

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Message::observe(MessageObserver::class);
    }
}
```

When I run the console command which creates a new message the terminal shows this:

```
php artisan chat:broadcast asdasd
[2016-12-15 16:26:44] local.INFO: Broadcasting [eventname] on channels [channel] with payload: {...}
```

Note: most of the names are confidential so I've used placeholders like eventname, channel etc, but I hope the relevant info is there.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Laravel 5.1. Funny thing is that it *was* working and then mysteriously stopped. Haven't figured out why yet. I can tell you that it's not the vagrant VM that's interfering... we had it working on the VM.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that BROADCAST_DRIVER in `.env` file is set to pusher like this

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
```

and in  `broadcasting.php` modify the potions array like following code

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver'  => 'pusher',
    'key'     => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
    'secret'  => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
    'app_id'  => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
      //leave these empty in your code
    ],
],`
```

Save this changes and run your laravel server i hope this will work for you ...!!

Comment: Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877837/how-can-i-make-realtime-notification-for-user-who-are-not-login

Answer (score 3):

Before broadcasting any events, you will first need to register the  App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider. In fresh Laravel applications, you only need to uncomment this provider in the providers array of your config/app.php configuration file.

```
     /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    //App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

.env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_ID=app_id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=auth-key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=secret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=cluster
```

you can fire event in controller like this

```
broadcast(new NewMessage($message));
```

and you can run `php artisan config:cache` to ensure